# Why cannot we use limit multiply rule instead of product rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

We use product rule for a complicated function like this u(x) v(x).

For instance,

$$ y = u(x) * v(x) $$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = u'(x)v(x) + v'(x)u(x)$$

However, I want to know why we cannot write like this:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{du(x)}{dx} * \frac{d v(x)}{dx}. $$

where,
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} [u(x) * v(x)] $$
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} u(x) * \lim_{x\to 0} v(x)$$
$$u'(x) = L $$
$$ v'(x) = M$$
$$u'(x)*v'(x) = LM $$

We use this rule to prove the limit product rule. Thus, why cannot we use this later approach directly for these type of complicated functions?

Comment: You’re a member for over 3 years. Can you then take the time to use MathJax to write your questions? Also an equation like *dy/dx = dy/dx u(x) * dy/dx v(x)* doesn’t make sense. Lastly, if you look at a proof of the derivative of the product, you’ll understand why it is like that.

Comment: If you have a large rectangular parking lot and increase the width by say $2$ feet and increase the length by say $3$ feet, does the area increase by just $6$ square feet?

Comment: @paw88789 My sincere apologies. As my midterm had hit really hard, I rushed it without even caring for the clarity.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I want to know why we cannot write $\left[\displaystyle (uv)' = (uv)'\cdot u \cdot (uv)'\cdot v \right]$:

It quite obviously isn't true. For a simple counterexample, take $u(x)=v(x)=x$, which gives a LHS of $(x^2)'=2x$ but a RHS of $(x^2)'\cdot x\cdot (x^2)'\cdot x=4x^4$, which quite clearly aren't equal.

If you have a conjecture (something that you think is true), you should be able to test it with some simple examples and find that it does indeed apply.

But if you could **provide your argument or proof** for why you think the rule should hold, and edit that into the question body, we might be able to help you better understand how your reasoning is faulty. The equation is false, so you have undoubtedly made an error when deriving it.

As for why the product rule should hold, there are countless proofs of it online.